# Retrieve only message bodies, or messages smaller than a given size, using fetchmail, getmail, etc

Tags: email, fetchmail

Using fetchmail, getmail, or other command-line MRAs, is there a way to retrieve only message bodies (without attachments) or only messages smaller than a given size? (This feature is available in Thunderbird, but that's not command-line friendly.)

Comment: Probably not.  And strictly speaking, it's probably not possible in Thunderbird, either... as to strip out attachments requires reading the entire message contents, then discarding the unused parts--so even Thunderbird probably retrieves that data before it can discard it.  What are you trying to accomplish? Conserving bandwidth, or disk space, or what?

Comment: The most important thing for me is retrieval speed. Disk space is second to that, and bandwidth usage third. I'm looking for a configuration option that tells the MRA not to download messages larger than a given size.

Comment: Flimzy, you don't know your IMAP.  ☺  Read RFC 3501 § 6.4.5.